# Effect of Moment of Inertia on Bifilar Pendulum Time Period of Oscillation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

During my Investigation into Bifilar Pendulums I found there was a positive correlation between Moment of Inertia and the time period of oscillation of the Bifilar Pendulum swings. Why does a higher moment of inertia cause an increase in time period for oscillations?

Comment: Have you had a look at the derivation of the time period for such a pendulum?

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find my answer. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @ArkieMandziy - Hi. Welcome to SE. As an reminder, you can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark if you think it's correct (I think, after 15 hours, you can do this).

Comment: Angular acceleration is inversely proportional to MMOI and period is inversely proportional to angular acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

The moment of inertia of the test object has a positive correlation to the time period of oscillation of a bifilar pendulum. This is because an increase in the moment of inertia causes the required force to rotate the test object to increase and thus slows down the speed of angular momentum causing the time taken to complete a singular oscillation to increase.